# Is there any way to override iOS TextInput default behavior of putting an ellipsis when text overflows in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

[image: Overflown text input with ellipsis at the end]

Is there any way of overriding iOS default behavior of placing ellipsis at the end of `TextInput` when text overflows? What I want to be able to see are the last characters before the text is truncated.

You can reproduce this with any `TextInput`. Below is some example code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

 export default function UselessTextInput() {
   const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('Useless Placeholder');

   return (
     <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: why a `TextInput` should put ellipsis when we usually need to scroll/select the input text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiline` attribute as follows. `numberOflines` specify the number of visible lines (height) in screen. If text more than 4 lines, then it will add scroll automatically.
Please note, I have removed height from the style.

```
<TextInput
    multiline
    editable
    numberOfLines={4}
    maxLength={4000}
    style={{ borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
    onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
    value={value}
/>
```

Comment: Adding multiline definitely gets rid of the ellipsis, but introduces some other undesired behavior. Nonetheless, I really appreciate your answer. Thank you.